# Specify number of significant digits for Django DecimalField

Tags: python, django, postgresql

The Django [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#decimalfield) is clear that DecimalFields are a fixed-precision decimal number, based on the Python [decimal module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html?#module-decimal).

If I have pre-existing data with 12 significant digits, how should I adequately model this?

For example, here's a sample of the data of interest:

```
shape_leng    |  shape_area
--------------+--------------
1530.79895768 | 90408.0667370
1936.60719682 | 182948.426626
232.229916910 | 1961.07387818
298.135367400 | 1206.32979471
7492.74283181 | 351026.396309
2284.47421526 | 240449.624361
1190.40843206 | 85766.7212220
579.035061001 | 17493.1577514
2532.91949894 | 343607.358136
3332.89318722 | 709775.074538
3259.11802943 | 378845.260875
3482.11473711 | 727006.254061
```

Some entries only have 6 decimals, while others have as many as 9 or 10. Since this is only a sample from the dataset, conceivably some could have an even greater range of values. Regardless, each entry has 12 digits and a decimal point.

In my first pass, I set the models to be:

```
shape_leng = models.DecimalField(max_digits=25, decimal_places=12, blank=True, null=True)
shape_area = models.DecimalField(max_digits=25, decimal_places=12, blank=True, null=True)
```

The downside is that I now am allowing for up to 25 digits, even though I know the true max_digits can only be 12 or 13.

Is there a better way to represent this? Some kind of variable-precision numeric type that only requires a scientific-style, significant digits type of precision?